# Best way to update an object's value in array (state) in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Currently, I made a simple cart in Vue with Vuex. The issue I'm having is that I'm updating the quantity of a product inside a cart object, but this does not update on the front-end view (it's not reactive).

What I've current done is updated an object value inside the `cart` array, for it to work I **needed** to set the existing cart to an empty array, then I re-applied the old cart with the new value to the cart state.

What would be the best way to update a value of an object inside an array?

Here are the following relevant data from my module (vuex):

```js
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        cart: [],
        products: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Product sweater 2',
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Product sweater',
            }
        ]
    },
    mutations: {

        update(state, product) {

            const index = state.cart.findIndex(x => x.id === product.id)

            if (index !== -1) {
                state.cart[index].quantity++
                state.cart = [
                    ...state.cart
                ]
            } else {
                product.quantity = 1
                state.cart.push(product)
            }
        },
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vue.set and Vue.delete to change array and object in vue.js.
Vue.set is a tool that allows us to add and change a property to an already reactive object.

[Vue.set - API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

[Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you send the index of the object such that it will be easy to update the particular value without searching for the item in the array else you can follow the below approach

```
mutations: {
    update(state, product) {
        // Find index of the item to be updated
        const itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(x => x.id === product.id)
        state.cart[itemIndex] = product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done it your way, with index, and it works, but it's unfortunately not reactive

Comment: Are you use `mapState` in your vue component?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Code is self-explanatory

```js
mutations: {
    update(state, product) {
        // Find product index in cart
        const index = state.cart.findIndex(x => x.id === product.id)
        if (index !== -1) {
            // If product is found, update properties
            let productFound = state.resources[index]
            productFound.quantity++
            // Update the product in state
            state.cart = [...state.cart.slice(0, index), { ...productFound, ...product }, ...state.cart.slice(index + 1)]
        } else {
            // Add product to state
            product.quantity = 1
            state.cart.push({ ...product })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After trying your solution, it unfortunately did not work. it seems to not update the quantity and is not reactive